GOcircle function in GOplot not plotting correctly
I'm trying to create a GO circle figure for my bulk RNAseq data. I ran the original RNAseq analysis in R using DESeq2, and enrichGO for performing GO analysis.
I'm having difficulty with the GOplot package. I'm able to run the code for the specific figures I want to make within that package (for example, GOBubble() and GOcircle() commands both execute and output a plot, but my genes don't seem to be getting attached to the GO terms). For example, the GOCircle plot has no dots representing genes for the various GO terms, and shows no FC scale because it's apparently not reading the gene list properly. I've attached an image of this to show what I mean. I've been trying to follow the github instructions for this package as seen here: https://wencke.github.io/
I'm assuming it's an issue with my data files somehow. I didn't change ENSEMBL IDs to actual gene names in my DEG gene list data file or my GO analysis data file - would that be causing this issue?
Below is an example of my header and 1 row of data from both the "ResultsGO" data file and the "GeneComparison" data file
[header from GO results data file](https://i.sstatic.net/fdOs0.png)
[header from gene DEG results data file](https://i.sstatic.net/uQ8vQ.png)

I've tried reformatting my excel files to be identical to the formatting from the github example, but result in the same issue.
I'm not too sure how to change ENSEMBL IDs to gene names in the GO analysis data file since a bunch of genes are listed horizontally in the same row. I'm going to try to figure out how to do this to see if that fixes the issue, but I don't see any mention of this being a necessity in the github document above.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
